# Cakephp : filtering foreach result in a table

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach, filter

I'm iterating through companies and users table to display my companies with their respective admin and author.

However my filtering isn't right, I use $user->role here to check faster than going through the database and comparing. And I get some authors in my admin column and vice versa.

foreach ($companies as $company) {?>
                    id?>">

```
                     <td><?= $company->name?></td>
              <td><?= $company->city?></td>
              <td><?= $company->group?></td>


                 <?php foreach ($company->users as $user) {?>
                <?php
                        if($user->role == 'admin'){
                        ?>
                            <td><?= $user->lastname?> <?= $user->firstname?> <?= $user->role?></td>
                                    <?php

                        }
                        if($user->role == 'author'){?>
                            <td><?= $user->lastname?> <?= $user->firstname?> <?= $user->role?></td><?php
                                    }
                     }

                }
```

How I can properly filter in my second foreach so that all admins get in admin column and authors in author column ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a foreach :

```
 foreach ($companies as $company) {?>
                <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="companies/edit/<?= $company->id?>">

                     <td><?= $company->name?></td>
              <td><?= $company->city?></td>
              <td><?= $company->group?></td>


                 <?php foreach ($company->users as $user) {?>
                <?php
                        if($user->role == 'admin'){
                        ?>
                            <td><?= $user->lastname?> <?= $user->firstname?></td>
                                    <?php

                        }
                     }?>
                      <?php foreach ($company->users as $user) {?>
                <?php

                        if($user->role == 'author'){?>
                            <td><?= $user->lastname?> <?= $user->firstname?> </td><?php
                                    }
                     }

                }
```